# how to make loop until I get positive definite matrix?

Tags: r, matrix, while-loop, do-while

I am trying to make a 3x3 symmetric matrix by randomly generating each elements like this
|a  b  c|
|b  d  e|
|c  e  f|

`a <- rnorm(1,0,3); b <- rnorm(1,0,3); c <- rnorm(1,0,3)....`

While doing this, If the matrix is positive definite then I am going to use but if is not positive definite then I want to regenerate the elements of the matrix.

How should I do this in R? Do I need to use `while` function?

Answer (score 1):

I'd approach the problem in another way. I'd build a diagonal matrix with just positive values (which is positive-definite by construction) and then build a random change of basis matrix so I can transform my diagonal matrix, keeping the property to be positive definite. For instance:

```
set.seed(1)
#number of dimensions
n<-3
A<-diag(runif(n,1,10)) #you can change the range of the eigen values
#define the change of basis matrix
C<-matrix(rnorm(n^2),ncol=n)
#transform A
res<- solve(C) %*% A %*% C
```

As we can see the eigen values are preserved:

```
eigen(A,only.values=TRUE)$value
#[1] 6.155680 4.349115 3.389578
eigen(res,only.values=TRUE)$value
#[1] 6.155680 4.349115 3.389578
```